# Replaced a broken power supply with a new one, now a bunch of weird things are happening

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, runtime-error

**Overview:**

I replaced a blown power supply with a new power supply in a desktop computer and now a bunch of weird errors are popping up everywhere (Steam, Malwarebytes, Microsoft Security Essentials, etc).

**Problem:**
[image]

Looking further into the causes the programs affected all seem to think the current year is 11911... and this problem seems to extend to a lot of other programs that are trying to communicate to the Internet like Java Updater and iTunes,

**My Thoughts:**

I thinking that perhaps the power supply forced a CMOS reboot when it blew, thus causing this random date to be stored as something most of these programs pull in. You can see the actual operating system date says 2011 and not 11911.

Can anyone assist with this?

**New Findings:**
Tried to update the time inside of Date and Time but when I go to the internet time tab I am greeted by the auto time updater saying that it will check time sync again in the year 11911... hmm strange.

Comment: Go into the bios and check the time, also make sure the it's not set to UTC as Windows sometimes has problems when hwclocks report time in UTC.

Comment: Bios time is ok... and with that restart programs are starting to come up properly but they are still failing whenever they try to connect to anything on the web (I am thinking this has to do with the date mismatch)

Comment: It has to do with the worng time that Windows is reporting. And Windows uses the System clock to set its time at boot. Then it will try resync with the time server periodically. Hence the problem lies with the Hardware clock.

Comment: Hmm so should i remove the CMOS battery to try to reset it and then input the correct date into bios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking system memory with MemTest86+ and Prime95. Maybe it got burned too?

I had similar issues on new PC which had memory modules with some unstable/unreliale cells. Prime95 showed errors in 3-5 minutes after starting memory-intensive test, and MemTest86+ took 30-40 minutes to detect an error.

By moving memory modules to another PC and confirming test results there, I was able to isolate the cause of error.